# Персонаж проходит сквозь стену, Unity

Tags: unity3d

В 2D игре в Unity есть игрок, передвигающийся с помощью `rigidbody2d.MovePosition()` (использование `rigidbody2d.velocity` и `rigidbody2d.AddForce()` ничего не меняет). К игроку прикрепленны компоненты `RigidBody2d`(dynamic) И `Capsule Collider2D`, у стены(созданной с помощью Tilemap) также имеется `RigidBody2d`(static), а также `Tilemap Collider 2d`, `Composite Collider 2d`.
Но проблема в том, что игрок проходит сквозь стены.
[image: Стены]

[image: Персонаж]

Что я делаю не так? Пытался гуглить, но кажись я слепой, раз решения не нашёл.

Comment: попробуйте убрать "IsTrigger"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Всё работает, не замечал включенную галочку)